# Show System Message banner when not logged in

Tags: bug, status-completed, system-message

The System Message banner is currently only being shown to users that are logged in.  I think it would be beneficial to display it to all users, regardless of their login status.

**Logged In:**
[image: Logged in]

**Logged Out:**
[image: Logged out]

Comment: If that is the only message that is displayed, I don't need to see it again.  All other messages display to all users logged in or not, AFAIK.

Comment: The system message is both changeable and deletable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of the SE 2.0 sites being split across multiple servers, causing the system message to be in the cache for one but not the others.

After about an hour the problem fixes itself, because the old system messages fall out of cache.

This isn't really ideal though, so sometime tonight new code will be going out to make removing/setting System Messages work across all server's nearly instantaneously (maximum lag time of about 30 seconds).

Comment: Ah.  The first time I noticed it was when I went to English.SE for the first time after the system message was mentioned.  I had to login in order to see it.  I then tested it on WebApps.SE by using incognito mode while being logged in in my main browser window.